Search with the combination of 2 fields in elasticsearch
i have a search phrase it contains text belongs to both song and category fields or either one
eg:- song name reverb
both search phrases can have more than 1 word and there is no differentiating factor in the search phrase to tell which belongs to which field
How do i handle this use-case in DSL query
currently using this query for 1 field match
"wildcard": {
   "song.keyword": {
       "value": "*song name*"
   }
}
            


Before posting, please check Elasticsearch documentation and Stack Overflow threads Example on searching across multiple fields in Elasticsearch. You might find the bool query with fuzzy matching solution you're looking for.
